# How to auto-add legend in [R]?

Tags: r, legend

```
plot(airquality$Wind, airquality$Ozone, col=airquality$Month)
```

How can I add a legend to the plot with correctly assigned colors other than by manually figuring out which color codes for which `Month`?

---

EDIT
And after ordering one gets a really nice plot:

```
with(
    airquality,
    xyplot(airquality[order(Wind), ]$Ozone ~ airquality[order(Wind), ]$Wind,
    groups=Month, type="b",
    auto.key=list(title="Month", corner=c(0.95, 1.0)))
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The numbers contained in `airquality$Month` define specific colors (as well as specific months). You can have R use these numbers when constructing the legend:

```
legend('topright', month.abb[unique(airquality$Month)], 
       col=unique(airquality$Month), pch=21)
```

[image]

Alternatively, `lattice` provides the `auto.key` argument to, e.g., its `xyplot` function:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(airquality$Ozone ~ airquality$Wind, groups=airquality$Month,
       auto.key=list(title="Month", corner=c(0.95, 1)))
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
And the `ggplot` approach, as provided by @MrFlick in the comments.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(airquality, 
       aes(Wind, Ozone, col=factor(Month, levels=1:12, labels=month.name))) + 
  geom_point() + scale_color_discrete(name="Month")
```

[image]

Comment: And just for "completeness," you can do this with `library(ggplot2)` as well: `ggplot(airquality, aes(Wind, Ozone, col=factor(Month, levels=1:12, labels=month.name))) + geom_point() + scale_color_discrete(name="Month")`

Comment: It might be safer to use `col=factor(unique(airquality$Month))` in `legend` and `col=factor(airquality$Month)` in the original plot otherwise you are indexing the default `palette()` from `5:9` instead of from `1:5`.

Comment: Good point, @thelatemail. And if you need more than 8 colors, it's probably best to use/create a color palette (or provide a vector of the required number of colors) since colors are repeated when specified by number (i.e. 1, 9, 17, etc. are all black).